# How to get text on webpage by url (need some idea or advice)?

Tags: javascript, php

How to get text on webpage by url (need some idea or advice)?

Normally i use this code for get file data using url

```
<?PHP
$text = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/sometextfile.txt');
echo $text;
?>
```

Now I want to get all text on webpage using url.

Can I do that by PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: You're doing it with PHP,  yes you can do it with Js aswell.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to be sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the text from external URL then you can simply use file_get_contents function with strip_tags:

```
<?PHP
$text = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/sometextfile.txt');
echo strip_tags($text); // If you only need text not html structure
?>
```

Another PHP way of doing this is CURL. You can enable php_curl and use the curl method to do this(http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php).

Comment: No , i want to get text by url not by file .

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It uses jQuery-like selectors, pretty neat.

Comment: it's show only link in webpage. it's not show some text.